# two jquery sliders having same class name but the issue is on moving the slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>

<div class="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
```

---

```
$(".slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".slider-value").html(ui.value);
    }
});

$(".slider-value").html($('.slider').slider('value'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1899/

This has two sliders of same class name and slider value is shown in a paragraph having same span class, But if I select a slider I want the value of it alone to change But currently both are changing.

Comment: Please don't try and sidestep the SO rule of posting code in your question when linking to jsFiddle. You saw the warning when you entered your question.

Comment: what i can't understand?

Comment: What don't you understand? Post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the slider's slide function calls `$( ".slider-value").html( ui.value );`. This, as you can see, is changing the inner HTML of all elements with the class `.slider-value`. You need to change your selector to select a relative element instead. To do that, change:

```
$( ".slider-value").html( ui.value );
```

to

```
$(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s7uxtbu7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Weird but works:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.handle).closest(".slider").next( "p").find(".slider-value").html( ui.value );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1902/

[ui object description](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)
[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)