# Two jquery sliders having same class name but the issue is on moving the slider (2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Referring to a question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366622/two-jquery-sliders-having-same-class-name-but-the-issue-is-on-moving-the-slider).

```
<h1>Font Size</h1>

<div class="slider"></div>
<p class="font-display">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>

<div class="slider"></div>
<p class="font-display">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

---

```
$('.slider').slider({
  value:40,
  min: 24,
  max: 48,
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#font_size').val(ui.value + ' px');
    $('.font-display').css('font-size', ui.value);
  }
});
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/8q8xhrr7/

This has two sliders of same class name and slider font-size is shown in a paragraph (.font-display), But if I select a slider I want the font size of it alone to change But currently both are changing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/2/

Answer (score 1):

If the `font-display` is always after the slider you can change your jquery to `$(this).next().css('font-size', ui.value);`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/1/)

If it is not necessarily the next element you can specify which next to look for with `$(this).nextAll('.font-display:first').css('font-size', ui.value);`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/6/)

Comment: I've tried on my original code, and it does not work. I update the code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/10/)

Comment: @Yudi you didn't change the jquery to either of these in that fiddle

Comment: @deppem I've changed, but it still does not work https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/11/ How I can do that?

Comment: @Yudi you've changed the html, use the jquery `$(this).parent().next().css('font-size', ui.value);` with your new html

Comment: Sorry @depperm, I create new fiddle. You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/8q8xhrr7/ I change to my original code and try your first code. But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/5/

HTML:

```
<h1>Font Size</h1>
<div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <p class="font-display">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <p class="font-display">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;   
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

body, p{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.slider').slider({
  value:40,
  min: 24,
  max: 48,
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.find($('#font_size')).val(ui.value + ' px');
    parent.find($('.font-display')).css('font-size', ui.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have try your code, but not work. I have change my original code in my question, you can see in fiddle.

Comment: I have already made new fiddle with my original code, https://jsfiddle.net/8q8xhrr7/. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get the closest element... (can use first() to be sure).

Like this:

```
$(this).next('.font-display')
```

or

```
$(this).closest(..)
```

or getting the parent element then use find()

```
$(this).parent(..).find(..)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0epj2g83/8/

This is your working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8q8xhrr7/1/